# angular cdk drag & drop Directly by click event Instead of dragging

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop, angular13

angular cdk drag & drop :
how drag item to done List Directly by click event Instead of dragging
For example on the 'jotform' site , when we click on each item in Left section Items, it performs operations automatically and drag it to main list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's should be an easy case, if I got it well; you wanna move an Item from a list to another when the user clicks on a button, right?

```
moveItem(previousList, currentList, previousIndex) {
    // let assume that the user will move it as last element
    let currentIndex = this.currentList.length;
    transferArrayItem(previousList,
        currentList,
        previousIndex,
        currentIndex);
}
```

Comment: thanks, i changed previousList , previousIndex and currentList According to my own data and its work correctly in my custom method.